# How can I delete a file in AWS S3 with Sails? To upload, I use skipper-s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sails.js, sails-skipper

I just made an upload file to AWS S3 with sails and skipper-3 and it work well. Now, how can I delete a file in AWS S3 with Sails?

When I upload the file I store in the Database the URL to AWS S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS-SDK directly or one of the many wrappers to it available at `npm`.

Based on Amazon [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) you will have something like:

```
s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);  // error
    else     console.log();                 // deleted
});
```

`params`shall hold parameters as bucket, credentials, region, path. See the example at [Amazon nodejs examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html).

And, for sure you can use the AWS SDK for upload files and use other AWS services inside sails too.

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753411/aws-s3-delete-object-using-javascript) too.

Answer (score 5):

`skipper-s3` already contains functions to read,list or remove files.
I am using below code to remove some file from the AWS S3. You can use it like this:

`var skipper = require('skipper-s3')({key: KEY,secret: SECRET,bucket: BUCKET});
skipper.rm(imageName,function(){});`

Check the module functions on [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper-s3/blob/master/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

For single image delete at a time First, install:

```
npm install --save aws-sdk
```

Now write the below code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "your aws key",
  secretAccessKey: "your aws secret key"
});

s3.config.region = "your aws bucket region";


var params = {
  Bucket: "Bucket name",
  Key: "image name"
};

s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  // an error occurred
  console.log(data, "tttttttttttt"); // successful response
});
```