# Erasing AWS/S3 objects from Node.JS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Node.JS app using mLab as a DB and also AWS/S3 to store files.
I just implemented a functionality allowing the user to erase information from the mLab DB, this works fine.

The one thing I still have to do is to erase possible relevant information from AWS/S3, and this I don't know how to do yet.

I have already browsed the net and seen a couple of things, but nothing quite satisfying.

Can someone tell exactly (if possible clearly and simply) what I need to do (necessary npm module if there is, etc...) to be able to delete objects from my AWS/S3 bucket. A good tutorial on the subject would also be fine if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides an [SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/#Get_Started_Fast). First, ensure that you have [set your credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) in whatever way makes sense for you. Next install the sdk:

```
npm i aws-sdk
```

[Deleting an object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) from a bucket:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
  Bucket: 'examplebucket', 
  Key: 'objectkey.jpg'
};

s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else {
    console.log(data);           // successful response
  }
});
```

A couple of notes:

- There is also a [deleteObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObjects-property) function that can delete multiple objects with one call.
- Optional but recommended, if you are using a recent version of node, you can use [util.promisify](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) to turn the callback style that the AWS sdk uses into promises.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **SDK for JavaScript (v3)** is easier; you just need to follow a few steps to delete an object.

First install the **@aws-sdk/client-s3** package:

Using npm:([more package installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/))

```
npm install @aws-sdk/client-s3
```

Import `DeleteObjectCommand` and `S3Client` from `@aws-sdk/client-s3`

```
import { DeleteObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
```

Create a new instance:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({});
```

Create an asynchronous function for delete an object:

```
export const deleteObject = async () => {
  const deleteCommand = new DeleteObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "bucket_name",
    Key: "your_object_name_with_file_extension", // kayes_note.txt
  });

  try {
    const response = await s3Client.send(deleteCommand);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

For more info, see **official documentation** [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/s3/command/DeleteObjectCommand/)

Comment: Not necessary to have file_extension in the key. It is actually a good idea to use UUID in order to guarantee no naming conflict inside bucket / folder