# How to delete a file after downloading it from Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to delete a file after downloading from the aws-sdk s3 server?

I upload a file via the aws sdk, how can I delete the file after I upload the file from the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete an object on AWS S3 using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753411/how-do-i-delete-an-object-on-aws-s3-using-javascript)

Comment: That seems to be two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to perform Amazon S3 operations. You can find all sorts of code examples, inlcuding how to delete an object, for this SDK here in the AWS Github repo:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/s3/src

If you are not familiar with the AWS SDK for JavaScript, refer to the [DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html).